# AF Table Column Stretching Manually

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

In AF Table:  I need to stretch the Columns manually in my Application, may i know which property  we need to use for that

i am using JDeveloper 12.2.1.3.0

i tried Property called columnStretching="column:c6" it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the column to your backing bean and using the provided set methods to set the width: e.g. setWidth()